# How to use this inside a collection class

Tags: java, list, collections, this

How can I use THIS keyword to refer to the collection in a class which inherits from an ArrayList like this. I got an error at design time and IDE doesn't allow me to compile my code.

```
public class Company{

   private EmployeeCollection employees;

   public Company(){
      this.employees = new EmployeeCollection();
      this.employees.add(new Employee());
      this.employees.add(new Employee());
      this.employees.add(new Employee());
      this.employees.add(new Employee());
      this.employees.add(new Employee());
   }

   public void MyMethod(){
      Employee fourthEmployee = employees.getFourth();
   }
}


public class EmployeeCollection extends ArrayList<Employee>{

   public Employee getFourth(){
      return this[3];  //<-- Error
   }

   public Employe getEmployee(int id){
      for(int i = 0; i< this.size(); i++){ //<-- Error
          if(id == this[i].id){  //<-- Error
             return this[i]; //<-- Error
          }
      }
   }

}
```

Normally in C# I can do something like this

```
    public object test(int id)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.Count; i++)
        {
            if (this[i].ID == id)
            {
                return this[i];
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Lists aren't arrays, so array syntax won't work on them. You can use `this.get(3);` instead.

Comment: BTW you shouldn't see any error on `this.size()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `this` keyword, but you're problem is that you are using array access syntax on it, which isn't valid in Java. Replace it with a call to the `get` method.

```
this.get(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList`'s backing `Object[]` is private, so you can't inherit it. If you could, you would refer to it like `elementData[x]`.

You can get elements from the array by just calling `this.get(x)` instead.

However, from a design perspective, you're better off making a decorator class which contains the `ArrayList` and manipulates it in the way you need.